# Configure Sublime Text 3 Anaconda Package with different Python version

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 (ST3) on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.1, with the Anaconda package that enables you to run Python inside of ST3.

The version of Python that is running, when I run the "build" command is 2.7.10.

I want to use Python 3.5.0 instead.

**Question**: How do I configure Anaconda to use Python 3.5 instead of 2.7, and ensure that this is a global setting for ST3?

The current output from `sys.version` is:

`2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is by using ST3's built-in project settings.

- If you haven't already done so, goto `Project >> Save Project As...` in the menu to save the current workspace as a project.
- Then open the project's settings with `Project >> Edit Project`. Add something like the following:

  ```
  {
      "build_systems":
      [
          {
              "cmd":
              [
                  "/path/to/bin/python",
                  "$file"
              ],
              "name": "build system name"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

Replace `/path/to/bin/python` with the path to the Python executable you want to use.

Replace `build system name` with the name you want to call this build system (e.g., Python 3.5.0).

One nice thing about this approach is that you can add multiple build systems and chose different ones using `super+shift+p`, start typing 'Build With', and chose from the list of build systems.

**Update:**

You can make a new global build system by going to `Tools >> Build System >> New Build System...` or using `super+shift+p` and typing 'Build: New Build System'. Replace the template it provides with:

```
{
    "cmd":
    [
        "/path/to/bin/python",
        "$file"
    ],
}
```

Be sure to replace the path as done above. When you save, it should prompt to save it in your user settings directory. Name it `Python-3.5.sublime-build` or something appropriate. You will need to specify to use that build by selecting it when building or by going to `Tools  >> Build System >> Python-3.5`.

To get around having to select the build system, your other option is opening ST3's version of the Python build system. On my OS X machine, I did this by going to `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages`. Inside, you will see a file called `Python.sublime-package`. This is a zipped file. You can add the `.zip` suffix and unzip it to access its `Python.sublime.build`. That file (for me) looks like:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```

You can either prepend Python's path to both instances of the `shell_cmd` or add a couple instances of `"path": "/path/to/python/directory/",` at the same level as `shell_cmd`.

You will then need to re-zip (and remove the `.zip` extension).

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Is there a way to set this globally, or just in the project settings?

Comment: @TrevorSullivan - I added two more options for global build systems. Disclaimer: I haven't tested the final option that I described.

Answer (score 0):

You can override Sublime Text 3 package settings by creating a folder with the package name in the subfolder `Packages` of your ST3 config folder and creating config files there with the same name.

User config folders:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/`
- macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`

In this case create a subfolder named `Python` and either unzip the installed `Python.sublime-package` file from the ST3 installation to this folder to alter the sublime-build file, or just create the following file named `Python.sublime-build` in this folder:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python3 -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python3 -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```

With this way, you don't need to alter any of the installation files, which otherwise could be overwritten by an update of ST3. And it is still the default Python build target.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your anaconda user settings on `Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings-User` by adding the python version you want as `"python_interpreter": "python3",` (or whatever python).

**E.G.**

```
{
    "auto_formatting": true,
    "autoformat_ignore":
    [
        "E309",
        "E501"
    ],
    "pep8_ignore":
    [
        "E221",
        "E266",
        "E309",
        "E501",
        "E722",
        "W503"
    ],
    "anaconda_linter_phantoms": false,
    "anaconda_linter_underlines": false,
    "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",
    "display_signatures": false,
    "disable_anaconda_completion": false,
    "auto_complete_triggers":
    [{"selector": "source.python - string - comment - constant.numeric",
                  "characters": "."
                }
    ],
    "python_interpreter": "python3",
}
```